# How to count the value in textbox?

Tags: c#

```
Format = PPYYMMNNNN
```

i just need to know how to count only the letter N.
The example that i found is to count all the letter.
i already tried some code but not working i don't know where is the error.

```
        format = docctrlTable.format;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < format.Length; i++)
        {
            String a = format[i] + "";

            if (a.Equals("N"))
            {
                count = count + 1;
            }
        }
        return count;
```

Comment: What is the error  you're getting?

Comment: if i change the format to PPYYMMNN only 2 N, it still get 4 n

Comment: Well, it works for me!

Comment: Your code is working, the format must not be the one you think it is.

Comment: ya i change it and it works..Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
    string Format = "PPYYMMNNNN";
    int count=0;
    foreach(char c in Format)
    {
        if(c=='N')
            count++;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(count);
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in a single expression.

```
int countOfN = format.Count(c => 'N' == c);
```

This works using the `LINQ` function [`Count()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181(v=vs.110).aspx) which uses a predict expression to match the elements to match.